# Why Sikuli clears texbox automatically and how to disable it?

Tags: sikuli

I am trying to automate one workflow for one software that I am using on my work.
This software was not developed by me, so I do not know implementation details.

I am using Sikuli IDE 1.0.1

What I need to do is:
1. press one button
2. input some text in textbox
3. press another button

I have done this successfully in IDE as separated steps.

This is problem:
I do not know why but after step 2, after I input text in text box and go to step 3, to press another button, text from textbox disperses.
I do not have this problem when doing thing manually.
I have tried to reproduced it manually, but with no success.
Even if I press first button again, in manual mode text stay in textbox.
So I do not understand why it is cleared when doing this in Sikuli.

Any help is appreciated.

By manual mode I am thinking on using mouse and keyboard by hand, not automatically by Sikuli.

Comment: Unclear to me, but I don't know about sikuli. Is this a programming question ? Could you add some code to the question ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found one workaround for this problem.
But if somebody have other solution he can post it also :-)

I have noticed that after using function click("name of image") for first button, I have focus on text box. After that I can use type("some string"). And to click on last image I can use type(Key.TAB) and after type(Key.ENTER).

By doing in this way, program is also faster.